# How to save a doc file in vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, com-interop

I am trying to save a doc file using an iterop object in vb.net. But i can't save it. It's always showing the error "Bad Filename". What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
If Len(Trim(hpath)) > 0 Then
    Dim objWord As Object
    objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Dim fN As String = ""
    fN = hpath
    If Not fN.Contains("~") OrElse Not fN.Contains("$") Then
        objWord.Documents.Add(hpath)
    End If
    objWord.Documents("F:\Sir\Newdoc.dotx").Save()
    MsgBox("Created...!")
Else
    MsgBox("File doesn't Exist...!")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Here I am converting my html page to a word document and saving the word document directly. I'm able to convert the html document to a word document but I am not able to save the word document, it's always shows the error "bad filename".

Comment: One reason for that error is if the file extension is wrong. Does it let you save it with an extension of ".docx"?

Comment: ...oh, and if you don't supply a file extension, it will add the correct one for you.